# Convert CamelCase to underscore_case

Tags: regex, oracle, uppercase, camelcasing

I'm trying to convert column value from CamelCase to underscore_case, this is what I tried :

```
SELECT regexp_replace(ColumnName, '([A-Z])', '_\1', 2) FROM Table;
```

but this will return `d_a_r_k_C_y_a_n` for the value `darkCyan`.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question can be tricky, possibly even a can of worms, because camel case can have some edge cases which are hard to handle.  Consider the following camel case string, which happens to have an all uppercase acronym in the middle of it:

```
myIBMComputerIsSlow
```

If we want to treat each letter in the acronym `IBM` as a separate word, then the answer given by @wiktor covers this problem well.  We would then end up with the following:

```
my_I_B_M_Computer_Is_Slow
```

If, on the other hand, we want to preserve the acronym, then we have to do more work:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE ('myIBMComputerIsSlow', '([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])',
                                   '\1_\2', 1, 0, 'c'),
                  '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\1_\2', 1, 0, 'c') AS output
FROM dual
```

This would output the following:

```
my_IBM_Computer_Is_Slow
```

In this case, we can insert an underscore break in the string under either of the two following conditions:

- a lowercase letter is immediately followed by an uppercase letter
- an uppercase letter is followed by upper, followed by lower

Note that the second case is how we detect that an acronym is ending and a new camel case word is beginning.

If you wanted the entire output in lowercase, which is what your question seems to imply, then you could add another step and use the `LOWER` function.

### Demo

Comment: This does not consider the case when two uppercase letters are adjacent. `ABCD` would be unchanged rather than becoming `A_B_C_D`.

Comment: @MT0 To the contrary, I did this by design.  I assume that a camel case name like `ComputerIBM` should render as `Computer_IBM` and _not_ as `Computer_I_B_M`.  If you can provide a reference on camel case convention, then do so.  Otherwise, please refrain from calling other people wrong.

Comment: If you are making assumptions about the question then it is useful to include those assumptions in your answer so everyone knows what to expect. I did not state that the answer was wrong (equally I did not state that it was right) - I merely stated that it did not consider one case. If you have considered it and disregarded it then that is not stated in the answer and future readers who may visit this question may not be aware of the subtle differences between the two solutions here (yours will not put underscores between consecutive uppercase letters but Wiktor Stribiżew's answer will).

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
SELECT regexp_replace('AbcDef', '([A-Z])', '_\1', 2, 0, 'c') from dual
```

where `2` denotes the second char is the starting point to search for a match, `0` means all matches should be found, and `c` specifies a case sensitive search and replace.

See the [online test](http://rextester.com/GYI30032), result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The original poster's sql:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(ColumnName, '([A-Z])', '_\1', 2) FROM Table;
```

works fine in Oracle 12c sql, that is 'darkCyan' becomes 'dark_cyan'.