# Trying to change strings in a column (Snowflake sql)

Tags: string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, camelcasing

I have a column in my table in Snowflake called "A". In this column I have values such as `"groceryStore", "postOffice", "nordstromRackStore"` etc. The values are currently in camel case but I would like to change them so that they follow the format `"GROCERY_STORE", "POST_OFFICE", "NORDSTROM_RACK_STORE"` and so on. Is there a way to change the values to be all uppercase and have the words separated by an underscore in this? I'm not sure how to use regex for camel case format. Or even alternatively, is there a way to change the result format into camel case? As in change `"GROCERY_STORE"` to `"groceryStore"`? Thanks!

Comment: [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475014/convert-camelcase-to-underscore-case). Can be applied to snowflake as well.

Answer (score 1):

It (`REGEXP_REPLACE`), seems to work, unless I am missing something in the question.

Original data -

```
with cte(col1) as (
 select * from values
 ('nordstromRackStore'),('groceryStore'),('postOffice'),('thisIsComplexCamelCaseAndLongToo')
)SELECT * from cte;
```

| COL1 |
| --- |
| nordstromRackStore |
| groceryStore |
| postOffice |
| thisIsComplexCamelCaseAndLongToo |

After replace -

```
with cte(col1) as (
  select * from values
 ('nordstromRackStore'),('groceryStore'),('postOffice'),('thisIsComplexCamelCaseAndLongToo')
)SELECT upper(regexp_replace(col1,'([A-Z])', '_\\1', 2)) as snake_case_col from cte;
```

| SNAKE_CASE_COL |
| --- |
| NORDSTROM_RACK_STORE |
| GROCERY_STORE |
| POST_OFFICE |
| THIS_IS_COMPLEX_CAMEL_CASE_AND_LONG_TOO |